# how often are update_state() and call() method called and what are the dimension of the parameters in tf.keras?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I would like to know

(1) how often the call() method of tf.keras.losses.Loss
and the update_state() method of tf.keras.metrics.Metric gets called during a training:

- are they called per each instance (observation)?
- or called per each batch?

(2) the dimension of y_true and y_pred passed to those methods:

- are their dimension (batch_size x output_dimension)
- or (1 x output_dimension)

The following code snippet comes from
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate

For experiment I insert print(y_true.shape, y_pred.shape) in update_state() and I find that it is only printed once in the first epoch. From the print, it looks like y_true and y_pred have the dimension of
(1 x output_dimension) in this particular example but is it always the case?

So, additionally

(3) I would like to know why it is printed only once and only in the first epoch.

(4) I can't print the value of y_true or y_pred. How can I?

```
Epoch 1/3
(None, 1) (None, 10)
(None, 1) (None, 10)
782/782 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 0.5666 - categorical_true_positives: 22080.8940
Epoch 2/3
782/782 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1680 - categorical_true_positives: 23877.1162
Epoch 3/3
782/782 [==============================] - 3s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1190 - categorical_true_positives: 24198.2733
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x1fb132cde80>
```

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# Preprocess the data (these are NumPy arrays)
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype("float32") / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784).astype("float32") / 255

y_train = y_train.astype("float32")
y_test = y_test.astype("float32")

# Reserve 10,000 samples for validation
x_val = x_train[-10000:]
y_val = y_train[-10000:]
x_train = x_train[:-10000]
y_train = y_train[:-10000]

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_1")(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_2")(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax", name="predictions")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

class CategoricalTruePositives(keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, name="categorical_true_positives", **kwargs):
        super(CategoricalTruePositives, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name="ctp", initializer="zeros")

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        print(y_true.shape, y_pred.shape) # For experiment
        y_pred = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), shape=(-1, 1))
        values = tf.cast(y_true, "int32") == tf.cast(y_pred, "int32")
        values = tf.cast(values, "float32")
        if sample_weight is not None:
            sample_weight = tf.cast(sample_weight, "float32")
            values = tf.multiply(values, sample_weight)
        self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

    def result(self):
        return self.true_positives

    def reset_states(self):
        # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
        self.true_positives.assign(0.0)
        
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-3),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[CategoricalTruePositives()],
)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1) how often the call() method of tf.keras.losses.Loss and the update_state() method of tf.keras.metrics.Metric gets called during a training:

The call method of `tf.keras.losses.Loss` and the `update_state()` are used at the end of each batch.

> (2) the dimension of y_true and y_pred passed to those methods:

The dimensions of `y_true` is same as what you pass in `y_train`. The only change is, the first dimension of `y_train` will be **no_of samples** and in the case of `y_true` it will be **batch_size**. In your case it is `(64, 1)` where 64 is batch_size.

The dimensions of `y_pred` is the shape of output of the model. In your case it is (64, 10) because you have 10 dense units in final layer.

> (3) I would like to know why it is printed only once and only in the first epoch.

The print statement is executed only once because tensorflow is executed in graph mode. Print will only work in eager mode. Add `run_eagerly = True` in `model.compile` step if you want to execute tensorflow code in eager mode.

> (4) I can't print the value of y_true or y_pred. How can I?

Run the code in eager mode.

**Code:**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# Preprocess the data (these are NumPy arrays)
x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784).astype("float32") / 255
x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784).astype("float32") / 255

y_train = y_train.astype("float32")
y_test = y_test.astype("float32")

# Reserve 10,000 samples for validation
x_val = x_train[-10000:]
y_val = y_train[-10000:]
x_train = x_train[:-10000]
y_train = y_train[:-10000]

inputs = keras.Input(shape=(784,), name="digits")
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_1")(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation="relu", name="dense_2")(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax", name="predictions")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

class CategoricalTruePositives(keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, name="categorical_true_positives", **kwargs):
        super(CategoricalTruePositives, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name="ctp", initializer="zeros")

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        print('update_state', y_true.shape, y_pred.shape) # For experiment
        y_pred = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), shape=(-1, 1))
        values = tf.cast(y_true, "int32") == tf.cast(y_pred, "int32")
        values = tf.cast(values, "float32")
        if sample_weight is not None:
            sample_weight = tf.cast(sample_weight, "float32")
            values = tf.multiply(values, sample_weight)
        self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

    def result(self):
        return self.true_positives

    def reset_states(self):
        # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
        self.true_positives.assign(0.0)

class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
    print("Start epoch {} of training".format(epoch))
  def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):
    keys = list(logs.keys())
    print("...Training: start of batch {}".format(batch))
  def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    print("...Training: end of batch {}".format(batch))
        
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=1e-3),
    loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[CategoricalTruePositives()],
    run_eagerly = True,
)
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=3, verbose = 0, callbacks=[CustomCallback()])
```

**Output:**

```
Start epoch 0 of training
...Training: start of batch 0
update_state (64, 1) (64, 10)
...Training: end of batch 0
...Training: start of batch 1
update_state (64, 1) (64, 10)
...Training: end of batch 1
...Training: start of batch 2
update_state (64, 1) (64, 10)
...Training: end of batch 2
...Training: start of batch 3
update_state (64, 1) (64, 10)
...Training: end of batch 3
...Training: start of batch 4
update_state (64, 1) (64, 10)
...Training: end of batch 4
...Training: start of batch 5
update_state (64, 1) (64, 10)
...Training: end of batch 5
```

The above example will make the answer to your clear.